# How do I toggle a checkbox in Unity with code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I looked at the Toggle API and can't find a way to set it to checked with code.
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Toggle.html

The reason I want to do it is that I want to set a checkbox as checked depending on a setting when the game starts.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.Toggle.html Here is an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Toggle-isOn.html

Use the public variable `Toggle.isOn`.
Set it to true like this: `myToggle.isOn = true;`.

You probably looked for a method, but don't forget to also look at the public variables, as these are part of the API as well.

Comment: You are correct, I realize it was a dumb question and I should have looked closer at the API. Used to having methods, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

Toggle.isOn wont do anything, sorry. do this:

```
toggle.onValueChange.Invoke(true) //or false if you want to uncheck it
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, `isOn` is not worked.
I tried with below code.

```
toggle.Select();
```

and it will select this toggle button.

Answer (score 0):

I tested some cases:

```
toggle.Select(); // Could call callbackFunction but can't select

Toggle.isOn; // Will select and call callbackFunction

toggle.onValueChange.Invoke(true); // Could call callbackFunction but can't select
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).